# Why I can't ctrl - drag a button in the interface file?

Tags: interface-builder

I have this view controller:

[image]

It's a UITableViewController with static cells.
This is the structure of all screen: the table with static cells and two views(one up one down)

My issue is that I cannot Ctrl-Drag anything from this screen.
What is happening?

[image]

Comment: Do you literally mean you can't Ctrl+Drag from any control on the screen? Are you trying to ctrl+drag from the visual designer portion of the screen (first image) or from the list of controls (second image)?

Comment: Either way, when  I release in the interface file I don't see the create outlet option.

Comment: Check that you've set the custom class of your controller in IB correctly.

Comment: Alladinian please move that comment into an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably forgot to set the custom class of your controller in IB
[image]

Also a quick change to 'Automatic' mode in the Assistant Editor should show the respective files, if it doesn't then you know that probably IB doesn't have a clue about your subclass and that's why it prevents the connections.

[image]